# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSpotify.spotify.initialize')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-native-native-module

This is the relevant portion of my code (imports, etc. not included)

```
import Spotify from 'react-native-spotify';

let spotifyOptions = {
    "clientID": "69708bf2b35e4cc2b208fafa600ce9a9",
    "sessionUserDefaultsKey": "SpotifySession",
    "redirectURL": "MoodMixer://auth",
    "scopes": ["user-read-private", "playlist-read", "playlist-read-private", "streaming"],
};

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {

            Spotify.initialize(spotifyOptions, (loggedIn, error) => {
                if (error != null) {
                    Alert.alert("ERROR", error.message);
                }
            });
```

I keep getting this error when I run it

[Error in Expo IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V11Z7.png)

Comment: import Spotify from 'react-native-spotify';   (Uppercase letter 'S')

Comment: @gokcand It still doesn’t work!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this version](https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify), you're importing it wrong according to their readme. Remove your curly braces, making it a default import. You're currently trying import a named export that doesn't exist.

```
import spotify from 'react-native-spotify';
```

Comment: Yes. I am using that version, after i fixed the import... it still doesn’t work :(

Comment: If you installed it with `npm install react-native-spotify`, you're not using that version, you're using this version https://github.com/viestat/react-native-spotify

Comment: No I used Lufinkey’s npm install (github page)

Comment: `console.log` what the object is

Comment: I'm not sure how to do to that.